# Switch from user.php?user_id=$1/ to just user.php/$1/

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a URL which is /forums/user.php/?user_id=6/ , but I want it to just be /forums/user.php/6/ and work. How can I do that?

I tried to do add to the .htaccess to edit the URL but it didnt quite work and It was just blank

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user\.php/([^/]+)/?$ user.php?user_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I did this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user\.php/([^/]+)/?$ user.php?user_id=$1 [L] 

It just didn't work like as if you are trying to access user.php/user_id=sdfsdfsdf33/ or something

Comment: If your user ids are always numeric, you could simplify your htaccess rule - maybe try `^user\.php/([0-9]+)/ user.php?user_id=$1 [QSA,L]` instead?

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding details in the comments. Where is your htaccess file? In `/forums/` or the docroot?

Comment: the first character `^` in your regex rule means "match string starting with" which seems like you forgot about `/forums` there

Comment: If you really want to keep the full script file name (including the `.php` suffix) in your URL, then you most likely won't even need rewriting - accessing PATH_INFO via $_SERVER should get you access to the `/6/` part already, so you would only have to trim the slashes off of that.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forums/user\.php/([^/]+)/?$ /forums/user.php/?user_id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```